# Media Source Extensions (MSE) - Chrome for Android

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, chromium, media-source

As far as I can gather, Media Source Extensions are supposed to be implemented in the latest current version of Chrome for Android. On the [Chromium Dashboard](http://www.chromestatus.com/features/4563797888991232) there's also an indication that this should be working. However it seems that in practice it does not work (or at least does not work using the same API's used in Chrome for desktop).

I cannot seem to get it to work, and specifically, running [this example](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html) on an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S4) with KitKat and latest version of Chrome for Android results in a blank (black) video - it looks like the webm file is playing (if I replace the source with a webm file with sound I can hear the audio), however no video is showing.

Does this mean MSE is actually not supported yet on Chrome for Android? Is there any example someone knows of that suggests that it should in fact work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work AFAIK. File a bug with a specific test case?

Answer (score 0):

No it is supported. I verified that the demo you provided works on my HTC one with chrome 35. You could try [dash.js](http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.1.2/index.html) reference player and see if you can play H264 video. Your issue is probably related to using a version < 34 of chrome for android.

Comment: Thanks for checking it on your device, I am super glad to hear that it works on some devices. It looks like it might be an issue with Samsung Galaxy S4. Unfortunately, I have upgraded to Chrome 36.0.1985.122 and the problem persists (no change in observed unexpected behavior - still hearing the audio yet seeing a black screen).

Comment: I now checked the dash.js page using the same device and Chrome version. It seems that some videos work and some do not. Wondering if it might be lack of support for some of the codecs on my device.